# AT-Commands ESP8266 01: AT+CIPSTART: How to fix response Link type Error / Can't connect with TCP

Tags: c, tcp, arduino, esp8266, at-command

IS SOLVED

I am trying to connect an ESP8266 01 (Controlled thru an Arduino) as a Client to an ESP8266 setup as an Server via TCP with AT-Commands. But as soon as I send the command "AT+CIPSTART" the response is "Link type Error". The SDK version is 2.0.0.

I have tried it with AT+CIPMUX on 1 and 0 and with every Id but the response is always Link type ERROR
Left is the Server / On the right the Client
[image]

Edit: Some random times after a couple of restarts it works but only 3% of the time.
IS SOLVED

Comment: Can you show the full list of commands you are using? Have you connected to the wifi network before the `AT+CIPSTART` command?

Comment: Hi Johnny i found the answer but now i have a new problem.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Should i post an new Question for the second problem ?

Comment: Yes, you should only ask about one question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Answer. So what i did wrong was i didn't initialize the AP with AT+CIPMUX=1. That means it wasn't able to open multiple id. So i just deleted the "0," from AT+CIPSTART=0,"TCP".... to AT+CIPSTART="TCP"... and the command worked.
You can also just initialize the AP with AT+CIPMUX=1.
But now as soon as i send a message it disconnects/restarts and it won't receive the message. 
EDIT: SECOND PROBLEM IS SOLVED

Comment: Second Problem is also solved was a bug in my UART Buffer